# Elastic beanstalk deployment failing on npm install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm currently working on deploying a project to Elastic Beanstalk, but I'm getting a failure when trying to run `npm install` from my config file in the .ebextensions folder. The project's backend is using Rails in API mode, while the frontend is served from the app/client folder with React. I can deploy successfully and open routes served from the Rails API(..table_1/all), but nothing is rendered by React. In local testing I use 'yarn start' in the app/client folder.

As I'm a beginner when it comes to deployment and use of react I would appreciate all the help I can get fixing this. Based on the logs below I'm not really sure what to do.

This is my config file in .ebextensions

```
container_commands:
  01_npm_install:
      cwd: '/var/app/ondeck/client/'
      command: 'npm install --timeout 30'
      leader_only: 'false'
```

This is the error displayed in the EB CLI:

```
_ucsb_class_scheduler/Command 01_npm_install] : Activity execution failed, because: npm ERR! Linux 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64
  npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--timeout" "30"
  npm ERR! node v4.6.0
  npm ERR! npm  v2.15.9
  npm ERR! code E404

  npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/30
  npm ERR! 404
  npm ERR! 404 '30' is not in the npm registry.
  npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
  npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'client'
  npm ERR! 404
  npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
  npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

  npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
  npm ERR!     /var/app/ondeck/client/npm-debug.log
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

And /var/app/ondeck/client/npm-debug.log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '--timeout',
1 verbose cli   '30' ]
2 info using npm@2.15.9
3 info using node@v4.6.0
4 verbose install initial load of /var/app/ondeck/client/package.json
5 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from /var/app/ondeck/client/package.json
6 silly cache add args [ '30', null ]
7 verbose cache add spec 30
8 silly cache add parsed spec Result {
8 silly cache add   raw: '30',
8 silly cache add   scope: null,
8 silly cache add   name: '30',
8 silly cache add   rawSpec: '',
8 silly cache add   spec: 'latest',
8 silly cache add   type: 'tag' }
9 silly addNamed 30@latest
10 verbose addNamed "latest" is being treated as a dist-tag for 30
11 info addNameTag [ '30', 'latest' ]
12 silly mapToRegistry name 30
13 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
14 silly mapToRegistry registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
15 silly mapToRegistry data Result {
15 silly mapToRegistry   raw: '30',
15 silly mapToRegistry   scope: null,
15 silly mapToRegistry   name: '30',
15 silly mapToRegistry   rawSpec: '',
15 silly mapToRegistry   spec: 'latest',
15 silly mapToRegistry   type: 'tag' }
16 silly mapToRegistry uri https://registry.npmjs.org/30
17 verbose addNameTag registry:https://registry.npmjs.org/30 not in flight; fetching
18 verbose request uri https://registry.npmjs.org/30
19 verbose request no auth needed
20 info attempt registry request try #1 at 7:33:50 AM
21 verbose request id b42d3e8383778fa0
22 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/30
23 http 404 https://registry.npmjs.org/30
24 verbose headers { 'content-type': 'application/json',
24 verbose headers   'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
24 verbose headers   'content-length': '2',
24 verbose headers   'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
24 verbose headers   date: 'Thu, 16 Nov 2017 07:33:50 GMT',
24 verbose headers   via: '1.1 varnish',
24 verbose headers   age: '0',
24 verbose headers   connection: 'keep-alive',
24 verbose headers   'x-served-by': 'cache-sea1028-SEA',
24 verbose headers   'x-cache': 'MISS',
24 verbose headers   'x-cache-hits': '0',
24 verbose headers   'x-timer': 'S1510817631.695604,VS0,VE146',
24 verbose headers   vary: 'Accept-Encoding' }
25 silly get cb [ 404,
25 silly get   { 'content-type': 'application/json',
25 silly get     'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
25 silly get     'content-length': '2',
25 silly get     'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
25 silly get     date: 'Thu, 16 Nov 2017 07:33:50 GMT',
25 silly get     via: '1.1 varnish',
25 silly get     age: '0',
25 silly get     connection: 'keep-alive',
25 silly get     'x-served-by': 'cache-sea1028-SEA',
25 silly get     'x-cache': 'MISS',
25 silly get     'x-cache-hits': '0',
25 silly get     'x-timer': 'S1510817631.695604,VS0,VE146',
25 silly get     vary: 'Accept-Encoding' } ]
26 verbose stack Error: Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/30
26 verbose stack     at makeError (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:264:12)
26 verbose stack     at CachingRegistryClient.<anonymous> (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:242:14)
26 verbose stack     at Request._callback (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:172:14)
26 verbose stack     at Request.self.callback (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:200:22)
26 verbose stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
26 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:172:7)
26 verbose stack     at Request.<anonymous> (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1067:10)
26 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
26 verbose stack     at Request.emit (events.js:169:7)
26 verbose stack     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:988:12)
27 verbose statusCode 404
28 verbose pkgid 30
29 verbose cwd /var/app/ondeck/client
30 error Linux 4.9.58-18.55.amzn1.x86_64
31 error argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/node-install/node-v4.6.0-linux-x64/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "--timeout" "30"
32 error node v4.6.0
33 error npm  v2.15.9
34 error code E404
35 error 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/30
35 error 404
35 error 404 '30' is not in the npm registry.
35 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
35 error 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'client'
35 error 404
35 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
35 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
36 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Can you try removing the `timeout` attribute from your `config` file and write the same like this =>  `command: 'npm install'` ?

Comment: When doing so I first get a timeout
ERROR: The EB CLI timed out after 15 minute(s). The operation might still be running. To keep viewing events, run 'eb events -f'.

Comment: Then: ERROR: [Instance: i-03b6fcfd2369cf05d] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...n provided in package.json
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/npm-debug.log.
container_command 01_npm_install in .ebextensions/seed_database.config failed.

Comment: Then it seems like AWS tries to redeploy the instance multiple times while failing due to Environment health. INFO: Added instance [i-0f0cf531ffdc6028a] to your environment.
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Ok.
WARN: Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.
INFO: Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Ok.
WARN: Removed instance [i-0f0cf531ffdc6028a] from your environment due to a EC2 health check failure.

Comment: Eventually it succeeds again, but with a new NPM error. INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).
ERROR: [Instance: i-0cd37965248cbd7a1] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/ondeck/client/npm-debug.log.

Comment: For some reason while deploying without the timeout attribute, I'm unable to SSH into the instance to access the npm-debug.log

Comment: Any ideas? Or should I post this as a new question?